# An app can't load remote web content in the local context

Tags: windows-phone, win-universal-app, bing-maps, winjs

I m trying to integrate Bing Maps V8 SDK in a Windows Phone JavaScript app.

I m following the current sample: http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#loadMapSync+HTML

In the HTML page, when it comes to `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol'></script>`, I get the following error at app runtime: **An app can't load remote web content in the local context**

I understand what it means but I can't download the JavaScript file locally because this file also refers to other js files, etc. The problem remains the same. For the same reason, I m also unable to make an XHR request.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a Windows 10 UWP app or a Windows 8 Webview app? Note that this does work using Apache Cordova.

Comment: For testing purposes, it's a Windows 8 app. But in the future, I want it to be a Cordova app. How does it work with Cordova ? Using the Whitelist plugin ? If yes, please give me a code sample. Thanks a lot

Comment: Cordova hosts everything within an iframe and creates a wrapper around it. This is how it gets around the security restrictions.

Comment: I tried using Cordova but it's still the same. Do you mean that it's working by adding allowed URLs inside the app manifest ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples of how to load the Bing Maps control into a mobile app.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Cross-Platform-Bing-Maps-e96600d5#content

https://jkebeck.wordpress.com/2013/06/22/cross-platform-development-with-bing-maps-and-phonegap/

http://soulsolutions.com.au/bing-maps-on-iphone-with-phone-gapapache-cordova/

http://soulsolutions.com.au/showing-gps-position-on-bing-maps-with-phonegapapache-cordova/